# Reduction of quadratic form and geometric interpretation

Tags: quadratic-forms

I would like to reduce such equations. Is there a general method that could help me to understnad how to do so.
$$Q_1= xy + yz + zx + 2y + 1 = 0 \\ 
Q_2 = x^2+y^2+z^2-4xy -4xz-4yz-4z-4y+2x+1=0$$

This is what I tried :
$$\begin{align*} Q_1& =xy + yz + zx + 2y + 1 \\&=(x+z)(y+z)-z^2 +2y + 1 \\ &=\frac{1}{4}(x+y+2z)^2 -\frac{1}{4}(x-y)^2 -z^2 + 2y +1 \\ \end{align*}$$ but after that I don't how to continue the reduction.

For the second equation :
$$ \begin{align*} Q_2 &= x^2+y^2+z^2-4xy -4xz-4yz-4z-4y+2x+1 \\ &= (x-2y-2z)^2 - 3y^2-3z^2-4z-4y+2x+1\end{align*}$$ I don't think it is right.

Comment: What is the form you want to reduce it to?

Comment: @martycohen I am trying to reduce $Q_1$ and $Q_2$

Comment: Easiest description is, when the polynomial is not homogeneous, add in a new variable and multiply: your first one becomes $xy+yz+zx +2yt+t^2.$ After expressing as a sum of squares with coefficients, plug back in $t=1$

Comment: What’s the “geometric interpretation” that you mention in your title but nowhere else?

Answer (score 1):

matrix work for your first polynomial, after making homogeneous with a new variable $t,$ where $H$ is the Hessian matrix of the resulting form. The linear expressions that are squared in the "reduction" have coefficients in the rows of $Q.$ The entries of $D$ give the coefficients for double the original form, so you need to be careful, divide the $D$ numbers by two, and check the results.

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 3 & 1 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  - 4 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
3 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 2 & 0 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

================================================

Algorithm discussed at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia
$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 2 & 0 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  D_0 = H  $$
$$ E_j^T D_{j-1} E_j = D_j  $$
$$  P_{j-1} E_j = P_j  $$
$$ E_j^{-1} Q_{j-1}  = Q_j  $$
$$  P_j Q_j = Q_j P_j = I  $$
$$ P_j^T H P_j = D_j  $$
$$ Q_j^T D_j Q_j = H  $$

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 2 & 0 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  - 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 &  - 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 2 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 &  - 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 2 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 &  - 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{5} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  - 3 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{5} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  - 3 \\ 
1 &  - 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{5} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
3 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{5} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  - 4 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 &  - 1 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
1 &  - 1 &  - 3 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 2 & 0 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  - 3 \\ 
1 &  - 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  - 4 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 3 & 1 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  - 4 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
3 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 2 & 0 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$